# Padding with leading zero in string works in Solaris but not in RHEL

Tags: c, linux, string, printf, solaris

This program prints strings with leading 0s on one platform but not another.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   char test[20];
   char a[4]="a12";
   sprintf(test,"%019s\n",a);
   printf("%s\n",test);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Solaris : 0000000000000000a12
RHEL    :                 a12 (left padding with spaces)
```

How can I get leading zeros on both platforms?

Comment: The 0 flag works with only numeric conversions. Why can't you do something like putchar 0, 19 times and then print your string?

Comment: @SameerMahajan.its my requirement.it's working in solaris but not in linux.

Answer (score 5):

You're invoking undefined behaviour on both systems; that you're getting different results is a not-surprising consequence.

The POSIX specification for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) says:

> `0`
>       For `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, and `G` conversion specifiers, leading zeros (following any indication of sign or base) are used to pad to the field width rather than performing space padding, except when converting an infinity or NaN. If the '`0`' and '`-`' flags both appear, the '`0`' flag is ignored. For `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, and `X` conversion specifiers, if a precision is specified, the '`0`' flag shall be ignored. [CX] ⌦  If the '`0`' and `<apostrophe>` flags both appear, the grouping characters are inserted before zero padding. For other conversions, the behavior is undefined. ⌫

*(Note on parsing that statement.  The appearance of the '⌫' suggests that the 'other conversions' comment applies only to `0` and `'` appearing together.  However, checking the C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011), it says:*

> *`0`
>
>    For `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, and `G` conversions, leading zeros
>   (following any indication of sign or base) are used to pad to the field width rather
>   than performing space padding, except when converting an infinity or NaN. If the
>   `0` and `-` flags both appear, the `0` flag is ignored. For `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, and `X`
>   conversions, if a precision is specified, the `0` flag is ignored. For other
>   conversions, the behavior is undefined.*

*I think the end marker '⌫' is misplaced in the POSIX material.)*

Consequently, to get reliable behaviour, you'll have to be more inventive.  The first step is to remove the `0` from the format string.

You also need to increase the size of your buffer; you're writing beyond the end.

Maybe something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char test[25];
    char a[4] = "a12";
    snprintf(test, sizeof(test), "%19s\n", a);
    size_t leading_blanks = strspn(test, " ");
    memset(test, '0', leading_blanks);
    printf("%s", test);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0000000000000000a12
```

---

If you need to process multiple values in a single line, each of which needs to be zero padded, there are various ways to handle it.  One option is like this (where the use case is simplified by all the fields being the same size):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[128];
    char *data[] = { "a12", "syzygy.sv.example.com", "192.168.234.119", "Quasimodo" };
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%20.20s%20.20s%20.20s%20.20s",
             data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        size_t leading_blanks = strspn(&buffer[20*i], " ");
        memset(&buffer[20*i], '0', leading_blanks);
    }
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
00000000000000000a12syzygy.sv.example.co00000192.168.234.11900000000000Quasimodo
```

You can create more elaborate formatting with care:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Field
{
    int width;
    char pad;
};

static struct Field fields[] =
{
    { .width = 12, .pad = '0', },
    { .width = 30, .pad = '@', },
    { .width = 15, .pad = '.', },
    { .width = 25, .pad = '-', },
};
enum { NUM_FIELDS = sizeof(fields) / sizeof(fields[0]) };

static char *data[][4] =
{
    { "a12",     "syzygy.sv.example.com", "192.168.234.119", "Quasimodo"             },
    { "zzx2341", "zulu.za.example.com",   "192.168.23.19",   "Beowulf"               },
    { "reynard", "coffee.br.example.com", "192.168.5.9",     "William the Conqueror" },
    { "peanut",  "koala.au.example.com",  "192.168.93.12",   "Quasimodo"             },
};
enum { NUM_ROWS = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
    {
        char   buffer[1024];
        char  *bufptr = buffer;
        size_t buflen = sizeof(buffer);
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_FIELDS; j++)
        {
            int nbytes = snprintf(bufptr, buflen, "[%*.*s]", fields[j].width,
                                  fields[j].width, data[i][j]);
            if ((size_t)nbytes > buflen)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Overlength: %zu required\n",
                        sizeof(buffer) - buflen + nbytes + 1);
                return 1;
            }
            size_t leading_blanks = strspn(bufptr + 1, " ");
            memset(bufptr + 1, fields[j].pad, leading_blanks);
            bufptr += nbytes;
            buflen -= nbytes;
        }
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[000000000a12][@@@@@@@@@syzygy.sv.example.com][192.168.234.119][----------------Quasimodo]
[00000zzx2341][@@@@@@@@@@@zulu.za.example.com][..192.168.23.19][------------------Beowulf]
[00000reynard][@@@@@@@@@coffee.br.example.com][....192.168.5.9][----William the Conqueror]
[000000peanut][@@@@@@@@@@koala.au.example.com][..192.168.93.12][----------------Quasimodo]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[4]="a12";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (19 - strlen(a)); i++)
        putchar('0');
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the output that's desired.  What's wanted is 16 zeros and then the 3 characters from `a`.  If `a` was a 10 character string, that would be 9 zeros and the 10 characters from `a`.  Your code would have to be adjusted to achieve that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: it wasn't clear from the original question. This requirement can be easily accommodated in the code by using 19 - strlen(a) instead of constant 19 in the < condition of the for loop.

Comment: Given the sample outputs, I'm not sure what wasn't clear.

Comment: requirement is to print logs in a file, where few fields are padded with zero. above code is good for print 1 or 2 variables.i have to print around 10 variables using spritnf

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, the `%0..` format string modifier works only with numerical arguments.

For strings you need to manually create the padding and prepend the appropriate length before your actual string.

The `%.*s` format string modifier lets you specify the length of the string. You need to create a padding string that contains just `0`'s as

```
char test[10] = "abcd";
char padding[25];
memset(padding, '0', sizeof(padding));
printf("%.*s%s", 19-strlen(test), padding , test);
```

This will produce the desired result.

You can see the [Demo here](https://ideone.com/6UWn6f)

Since your question is about `sprintf`, clarifying that this will work in similar way with `sprintf` too. Just create a buffer of appropriate size that can accommodate the padding, the actual string and the null terminator.

Comment: i already knows this answer from google search but looking for some more efficient code because i have to use it for multiple variables.

Comment: @ajay even for multiple variables, all you have to do is to repeat the `printf` (or `sprint`). The `memset` only has to be done once and can be reused.